# How to append 3 tables with different number of columns in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, append, formula

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 3 tables with different number of columns where some columns are actually repeated in these 3 tables (as shown in the screenshot above).

`Table 1: Col A to Col D`

`Table 2: Col F to Col H`

`Table 3: Col J to Col L`

I want to merge these 3 tables together to reduce the number of columns in my google sheet. The screenshot below is how I process these 3 tables before merging.

[image]

I'm using `QUERY` to create extra columns for each table so that the number of columns and the position are aligned between 3 tables. After that, I use `QUERY` again to append the 3 processed tables as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

However, this method is very tedious when I have 10 tables or more. Is there any other easier ways or tricks to use so that I can achieve the same expected output as shown in the 3rd screenshot?

This is my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1gJAhp1RVax2fy8D-uEtFxdjb-zAHutkPFv5WZT_TY/edit#gid=0

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a really complicated formula to get the desired output which is a combination of multiple formula's

I added a new tab in you Google Sheet called "[Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H1gJAhp1RVax2fy8D-uEtFxdjb-zAHutkPFv5WZT_TY/edit#gid=853328817)" with this formula included

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({
IFERROR( ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!B3:D3&"~"&Sheet1!A4:A&"~"&Sheet1!B4:D),"~")),"");
IFERROR( ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!G3:H3&"~"&Sheet1!F4:F&"~"&Sheet1!G4:H),"~")),"");
IFERROR( ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!K3:L3&"~"&Sheet1!J4:J&"~"&Sheet1!K4:L),"~")),"")}), 
"SELECT Col2, SUM(Col3) WHERE Col2 is not null GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1 LABEL Col2 'Student Name' ")
```

Steps:

1. [Unpivot](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/unpivot-in-google-sheets/) each table  `=IFERROR( ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!B3:D3&"~"&Sheet1!A4:A6&"~"&Sheet1!B4:D6),"~")),"")`
2. Combine all tables into one table: `=ARRAYFORMULA({__Unpivot1__; __Unpivot2__, __Unpivot3__})`
3. [Pivot](https://medium.com/@prasanthmj/google-sheets-query-pivot-example-76229437946f) above data in Step2: `=Query(__Step2__, "SELECT Col2, SUM(Col3) GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1 LABEL Col2 'Student Name' ")`
4. Add `WHERE Col2 is not null` in the query to [remove any possible blank rows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_HxzNw-feA)

Comment: Thanks for your solution! The number of columns for each table is fixed but the rows might keep increasing. So I edited your formula by deleting the `6` behind. However, seems like there is an empty space (row 2) in "Solution" tab, how should I remove it?

Comment: You need to add `WHERE Col2 is not null` to the formula. I updated it in the sheet. Refer video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_HxzNw-feA